# Keystroke commands for open recent

Tags: keyboard

I want to set a keystroke command (Mountain Lion) to trigger the common File menu's Open Recent option.

I've tried the System Preferences => Application Shortcuts => Keyboard Shortcuts. My shortcuts show up in the applications' File => Open Recent menu, and when I type my assigned keystrokes there's a little flash in the File menu bar, but nothing else happens.

Any ideas, y'all?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to assign a shortcut to this script:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
    tell menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
        click
        repeat with x in {"Open Recent", "Open Recent File", "Recent Projects", "Open With"}
            if exists menu item x of menu 1 then
                click menu item x of menu 1
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

It opens an Open With menu in Finder and a menu for recent files in other applications.

There are other ways to assign a shortcut to a script using Quicksilver, Alfred, etc.